# IF something is True

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm attempting to write some simple code that will check to see if a particular directory exists AND if that directory contains any files. If it exists AND it contains files, then I want it to do something. If not, then I want it to do something else.

I've been using the os module to perform the file explorer operations and thus far, it seems to be working just fine.

```
if os.listdir("D:\Inventory\Joy\XL") != []:  #Checks to see if the directory is empty
    print("This directory is full")
else:
    print("This directory is empty")


if (os.path.exists("D:\Inventory\Joy\XL")) is True: #THIS ISN'T RIGHT BUT I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO.
    print("This directory exists")
else:
    print("The directory doesn't exist")
```

I've read that one should avoid using "if x == True then y" or "if x is True then y", but I don't know how (or why) to avoid it. Also, I woudn't know how to implement it even if I wanted to flout convention. People say it's redundant but, again, I don't understand why. I've read similar entries in Stack Overflow about this problem but I haven't understood any of the answers.

Comment: Yeesh, why are you `print`-ing in the condition? Also, did you experiment with removing `is True` from anywhere and see what happened?

Comment: `is` would be comparing a boolean to a boolean, but you start with something that can equate to a boolean so there isn't anything gained and you gain an extra assembly operation

Comment: `print` (besides printing stuff) returns `None`, which is not the same as `True`. Don't add your debugging output in the condition.

Comment: `if x == True` will pass if `x` is `True` **or** something that equates to the integer `1`.  `x is True` will **only** pass if x is the boolean `True`.

Comment: Hint: Would you rather say "Is the statement 'Ghosti is your username' true" or rather just "'Ghosti is your username'"? ... In code: `if x: y()`, when you have `is True` or `== True` it is just redundant

Comment: In future, please try to make your question more focused, it's not at all clear what exactly you're asking here.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to test that a list isn't empty is

```
if os.listdir("D:\Inventory\Joy\XL"):
```

which treats empty lists as false values and non-empty lists as true values.

Since `os.path.exists` returns a boolean, there is no need to do *anything* that will simply return another boolean; you already have one. Comparing a `True` value to `True` returns `True`; comparing `False` to `True` returns `False`, so you are just getting back your original input.

```
if os.path.exists("D:\Inventory\Joy\XL"):
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've read that one should avoid using "if x == True then y" or "if x
>   is True then y", but I don't know how (or why) to avoid it.

The preferred style looks like this:

```
foo = False
bar = True
if foo:
  print "Foo!"
elif bar:
  print "Bar!"
else:
  print "Someone broke logic!"
```

This style is preferred because it avoids the redundant "is True".

> People say it's redundant but, again, I don't understand why

It is redundant because for any expression e, evaluated in a boolean context, `e is True` == `e`. "Evaluated in a boolean context" just means that we're testing whether the value of the expression is one of the "Falsey" values `[False, None, [], {}, "", 0]`. If it is one of these values, the result is `False`. If not, it is `True`.

Comment: The main issue is he is printing in the condition.

Comment: I printed it in an attempt to see exactly how Python was behaving because obviously I'm still learning it.

Jon Kiparsky, as for the redundancy, I was unaware that it was assumed that conditions were true when evaluating them. That is utterly non-intuitive to me. Nevertheless, I understand that that's the case now. Thank you.

I understand fully that there are issues with the code, but I included it so an experienced person could correct it. I wrote it the way it makes sense to me. I'm still trying to figure out the best way to do it.

Comment: @Ghoti I may have not explained it clearly, but there is no assumption of truth here. `e is True` == `e` was meant as an iff, a two-way implication. Putting it another way: For any expression `e`, `e is True` is "truthy" if and only if `e` is "truthy". This is equivalent to saying `e is True` is "falsey" if and only if `e` is "falsey". Therefore `if e is True:` is always equivalent to `if e:` Is this more clear?

Comment: @JonKiparsky Thanks again for your help. Let me state that I *just* noticed the erroneous 'print' that the you had a problem with. That was a mistake in typing out the code on my part. Obviously, that print shouldn't have been there. I should have done a better job editing.

Incidentally, I took out the 'is True' and everything seems to be working properly now. I'm not sure that I understand just yet but admittedly I'm a bit distracted taking care of children. :-) I'll read your response again ASAP. Thank you.